# Scrollview in Relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a huge list of items which I put into linear layout and then I put that into scrollview to make it scrollable.

Then I wrap it all into relative view because I want to have add button at the bottom.

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

A LOT OF CONTENT


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:paddingTop="23dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Due to add button at the bottom whenever I scroll to the very bottom of the list, the add button blocks the bottom most part of the scrollview. How would I have scrollview fit only the part of screen that add button does not take up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set rule `android:layout_above="@+id/add"` to `ScrollView`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/add"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            A LOT OF CONTENT


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:paddingTop="23dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am sorry man, Peter was 3 minutes earlier, but I love your answer

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the scroll View:

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/add"
```